Probability and strictly increasing transformation
Let $X$ be a random variable on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),P)$ and let $\nu$ a (measurable) strictly increasing function. How to prove with a measure theoretic approach that:
$$
P(X \leqslant x) = P(\nu(X) \leqslant \nu(x)) ?
$$

Hint: being strictly continuou function, $\nu$ is invertible and it preserve the order of elements...

Simply take the events $A,B\subset\Omega$\begin{align}A&:=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\le x\}\\ B&:=\{\omega\in\Omega:\nu(X(\omega))\le\nu(x)\}\end{align} and show that they are equal, i.e. $A=B$.
Equal sets have the same measure, hence $P(A)=P(B)$ and we are done.
